# SAGA-GIS (2.3.1) fatal error during compilation (Ubuntu 16.04) hdf5.h not found in /usr/include/vigra/ subdir

Tags: ubuntu, saga, compilation

OS : Ubuntu 16.04

Compilation using : ./configure && make

I encountered a fatal error while compiling [SAGA-GIS 2.3.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/)  :

```
Making all in imagery_vigra
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/username/Downloads/saga-2.3.1/src/modules/imagery/imagery_vigra'
depbase=`echo vigra_random_forest.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
/bin/bash ../../../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../..    -fPIC -I../../../../src/saga_core -D_SAGA_LINUX -D_TYPEDEF_BYTE -D_TYPEDEF_WORD -D_SAGA_UNICODE  -fopenmp -lgomp -g -O2 -MT vigra_random_forest.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o vigra_random_forest.lo vigra_random_forest.cpp &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../.. -fPIC -I../../../../src/saga_core -D_SAGA_LINUX -D_TYPEDEF_BYTE -D_TYPEDEF_WORD -D_SAGA_UNICODE -fopenmp -lgomp -g -O2 -MT vigra_random_forest.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/vigra_random_forest.Tpo -c vigra_random_forest.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/vigra_random_forest.o
In file included from /usr/include/vigra/random_forest_hdf5_impex.hxx:41:0,
                 from vigra_random_forest.cpp:73:
/usr/include/vigra/hdf5impex.hxx:47:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:529: recipe for target 'vigra_random_forest.lo' failed
make[5]: *** [vigra_random_forest.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/username/Downloads/saga-2.3.1/src/modules/imagery/imagery_vigra'
Makefile:393: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/username/Downloads/saga-2.3.1/src/modules/imagery'
Makefile:393: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/username/Downloads/saga-2.3.1/src/modules'
Makefile:393: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/username/Downloads/saga-2.3.1/src'
Makefile:499: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/username/Downloads/saga-2.3.1'
Makefile:410: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have installed these two dependencies before :

> $ sudo apt-get install libvigraimpex5v5 libvigraimpex-dev

Answer (score 1):

keep attention on configure output. Your problem could be solved with the dependencies satisfaction:

```
aptitude install libgdal-dev
aptitude install libwxgtk3.0-dev 
aptitude install libproj-dev
```

Comment: Right concept, but I'm not sure those are really the right dependencies for HDF5....